# Azure VM can't reach remote network with connected VPN

Tags: azure, networking, vpn, azure-virtual-network

I am setting up an Azure VPN Gateway in order for my Azure VM to connect to a remote RTSP feed, following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal.

What I have done:

1. Create a virtual network + a subnet and a Virtual Machine
2. Create the VPN Gateway in the same virtual network
3. Create a local network gateway with the Public IP and IPs range of the remote network that contains the RTSP feeds
4. Create the site to site VPN connection with needed shared access key.

The status of the VPN connection is "connected", as you can see in below picture:

[image]

Moreover, the subnet on which my azure virtual machine is, is in the same virtual network as the subnet of the VPN Gateway:

[image]

From what I understand, as long as the VM is in the virtual network of the Gateway, I should be able to reach the remote network...

**Expected behaviour**: I should be able to reach the following IP addresses: 192.168.250.30/32 that are on the remote network, from my azure virtual machine.

**Actual behavior**: From my azure virtual machine, I'm still unable to reach the remote network.

Any ideas where the problem can come from?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons why your VM cannot reach onpremise network.
I would recommend you to check routes on your VPN onpremise device and network settings in Azure VPN Gateway. Do you still have Data In and Data Out 0 in Azure VPN Gateway?

Comment: Thanks for your support. Yes still 0. When you say checking network settings, what are you referring to?

Comment: Check If networks defined in Azure Local Network Gateway correctly then If VPN is established on you VPN on premise device and routing settings on  you VPN on premise device

Comment: All these things look good. 

However, when I run the command: `ip route` from my VM, there is no route toward the gateway subnetwork

Comment: You should see default gateway on your VM routing table.
Default Gateway is responsible for routing traffic further.
Can you see that tunnel is UP on your VPN onpremise device?

Comment: I don't have the VPN Gateway subnet (10.0.0.0/28) in my VM route table . I guess that's the issue? How can I add it ?

Comment: You may add route to VM using route command. Example: route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.240 [Your Gateway IP address]

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that the Azure VM's are not getting gateway routes, then a gateway reset should be tried first and the gateway reset needs to be done twice.

**Reference :**

[VPN gateway Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/reset-gateway#reset-a-vpn-gateway)

**References for S2S VPN issues troubleshooting:**

[S2S VPN cannot connect and stops working](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-cannot-connect)

[S2S VPN disconnects intermittently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-troubleshoot-site-to-site-disconnected-intermittently)

**Note :** If this doesn’t solve your issue then please reach out to Azure support for more troubleshooting as it may need assisted support by clicking (Support+Help) and creating a technical support request. Please validate your Onprem VPN device as well.

And as **Andriy Bilous** has mentioned in comments section:

> - You should see default gateway on your VM routing table. Default    Gateway is responsible for routing traffic further. Can you see that
>   tunnel is UP on your VPN onpremise device.
> - If no VPN Gateway subnet (10.0.0.0/28) in your VM route table - You    may add route to VM using route command. Example: route ADD 10.0.0.0
>   MASK 255.255.255.240 [Your Gateway IP address]